# Create pyspark dataframe from numpy to 2d arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyspark, numpy-ndarray

Hi I have multiple numpy arrays in below shape and format.

```
print(user_feature.shape)
print(service_id.shape)
print(target_id.shape)
print(target_label.shape)
print(service_label.shape)

Output:
(4621998, 620)
(4621998, 7)
(4621998,)
(4621998,)
(4621998, 7)


print(user_feature)
print(service_id)
print(target_id)
print(target_label)
print(service_label)

[[ 1.33677050e-02 -1.45685431e-02 -2.30765194e-02 ...  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  1.16669689e-04]
 [ 1.33677050e-02 -1.45685431e-02 -2.30765194e-02 ...  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  1.16669689e-04]
 [ 1.33677050e-02 -1.45685431e-02 -2.30765194e-02 ...  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  1.16669689e-04]
 ...
 [-5.55971265e-03  6.94929948e-03 -2.85931975e-02 ...  1.36206508e-01
   4.67081647e-03  7.43526791e-04]
 [-5.55971265e-03  6.94929948e-03 -2.85931975e-02 ...  1.36206508e-01
   4.67081647e-03  7.43526791e-04]
 [-5.55971265e-03  6.94929948e-03 -2.85931975e-02 ...  1.36206508e-01
   4.67081647e-03  7.43526791e-04]]
[[215. 215. 215. ... 554. 215. 215.]
 [215. 215. 215. ... 215. 215. 215.]
 [215. 215. 554. ... 215. 215. 215.]
 ...
 [116. 116. 149. ... 149.  44.  44.]
 [116. 149. 116. ...  44.  44. 297.]
 [149. 116. 149. ...  44. 297. 297.]]
[215. 215. 554. ... 297. 297. 176.]
[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
[[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 ...
 [2. 5. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [5. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]]
```

So I am trying to merge this arrays vertically and create a pyspark dataframe like, below is what I was trying, I have defined a schema and using that to create dataframe however I am getting below error. I also tried to convert individual numpy array into df (later merge all the df) but getting the same error on the schema. What am I missing here?

```
schema_fc = StructType( [ StructField("user_feature", ArrayType( ArrayType(FloatType()) ), False), 
                          StructField("sequence_service_id_list",  ArrayType( ArrayType(FloatType()) ), False), 
                          StructField("target_service_id",   ArrayType(FloatType() ) , False),
                          StructField("target_label",   ArrayType(FloatType() ) , False), 
                          StructField("sequence_label_list",  ArrayType( ArrayType(FloatType() ) ), False)] )

df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(train_user_feature, train_sequence_service_id_list, train_target_service_id, train_target_label, train_sequence_label_list), schema_fc)
```

> Fail to execute line 2: df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(train_user_feature, train_sequence_service_id_list, train_target_service_id, train_target_label, train_sequence_label_list), schema_fc)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/tmp/1692220704218-0/zeppelin_python.py", line 158, in 
> exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
> File "", line 2, in 
> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 675, in createDataFrame
> return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 700, in _create_dataframe
> rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 509, in _createFromLocal
> data = list(data)
> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 682, in prepare
> verify_func(obj)
> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1409, in verify
> verify_value(obj)
> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1390, in verify_struct
> verifier(v)
> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1409, in verify
> verify_value(obj)
> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1352, in verify_array
> verify_acceptable_types(obj)
> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1292, in verify_acceptable_types
> % (dataType, obj, type(obj))))
> TypeError: field user_feature: ArrayType(ArrayType(FloatType,true),true) can not accept object array([ 1.33677050e-02, -1.45685431e-02, -2.30765194e-02, -5.82330208e-03,
> -3.32775936e-02, -2.07596943e-02, -2.37267348e-04, -4.20683017e-03,
> -4.34294827e-02,  7.81743042e-03,  1.68688912e-02, -1.24656968e-02,
> 4.02029790e-03,  3.12208608e-02, -4.03045630e-03,  2.28498932e-02,
> 1.13157155e-02,  1.06274318e-02, -8.11346527e-03, -6.98270462e-03,
> -3.91414156e-03, -8.35975632e-03,  1.49020925e-05, -7.33336899e-03,
> 8.67067836e-03, -2.28234846e-03,  5.22214249e-02,  1.39330365e-02,
> 3.98872644e-02,  6.10537268e-03,  2.20239125e-02, -1.11836568e-03,
> -1.80659704e-02, -1.99369527e-02,  2.31389888e-02, -4.65059280e-02,
> 2.19357051e-02, -2.52697505e-02,  1.59132443e-02,  2.98593007e-02,
> 3.99250053e-02,  4.35081795e-02,  1.41635444e-02, -1.70806684e-02,
> 1.30436081e-03, -1.31941019e-02,  1.14841061e-02,  5.76580316e-02,
> 2.16435902e-02, -4.92058229e-03, -3.88808325e-02,  2.62990035e-02,
> -1.39478920e-02,  8.46350566e-04,  3.43511552e-02, -1.80143528e-02,
> -4.80983080e-03,  1.50774773e-02,  2.53398716e-02,  2.06974316e-02,
> 7.26055726e-03, -4.74966839e-02,  2.62531005e-02,  1.31620280e-02,
> -8.68222490e-03, -1.43548492e-02,  9.61813331e-03, -2.14950927e-02,
> 1.20869037e-02,  7.72804953e-04, -2.06626896e-02,  1.97541751e-02,
> 2.28899159e-02, -1.63509734e-02,  6.25781249e-04,  2.29061060e-02,
> 2.55851950e-02,  6.25669882e-02,  2.07121912e-02,  1.52262878e-02,
> -4.50072298e-03, -2.88834609e-03, -7.85173662e-03, -3.19551006e-02,
> -1.96053647e-02,  2.16488615e-02, -1.82419382e-02, -8.35052226e-03,
> 8.67485628e-03, -6.06879368e-02,  1.43139064e-02,  1.74148679e-02,
> 7.30755646e-03,  2.66504586e-02,  3.40831396e-03,  2.75030751e-02,
> 1.13305971e-02, -4.58726063e-02,  1.36343203e-02,  3.14601064e-02,
> -1.86643917e-02, -2.10148469e-03, -4.82135266e-02,  2.11269110e-02,
> 1.60128847e-02,  3.05281598e-02,  1.86553858e-02, -3.48868184e-02,
> -3.12457476e-02, -8.56714416e-03,  5.18892147e-02,  3.10956426e-02,
> -1.29655236e-03,  1.91727206e-02,  7.09275994e-03, -2.15799417e-02,
> 3.56485695e-02,  1.97729263e-02, -2.52993172e-03,  4.34201807e-02,
> 2.76413155e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.16669689e-04]) in type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Expected output

```
user_feature    service_id  target_id   target_label    service_label
[ 1.33677050e-02 -1.45685431e-02 -2.30765194e-02 ...  0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00  1.16669689e-04] [215. 215. 215. ... 554. 215. 215.] [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] [215. 215. 554. ... 297. 297. 176.] [5. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
[ 1.33677050e-02 -1.45685431e-02 -2.30765194e-02 ...  0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00  7.43526791e-04] [215. 215. 554. ... 215. 215. 215.] [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] [215. 215. 554. ... 297. 297. 176.] [5. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
[ 1.33677050e-02 -1.45685431e-02 -2.30765194e-02 ...  0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00  2.16669689e-04] [215. 215. 554. ... 215. 215. 215.] [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] [215. 215. 554. ... 297. 297. 176.] [5. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
[ 1.33677050e-02 -1.45685431e-02 -2.30765194e-02 ...  0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00  1.16669689e-04] [215. 215. 554. ... 215. 215. 215.] [1. 1. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.] [215. 215. 554. ... 297. 297. 176.] [6. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a Json with these data, using the JsonDF Package Json object, and with the output you can DataFrame it.

the code will be something like the following:

```py
from JsonDF.utils.Json.Json import Json

json_data = Json('json_data', {'user_feature': user_feature,
                               'service_id': service_id,
                               'target_id': target_id,
                               'target_label': target_label,
                               'service_label': service_label}).objectify()
```

the output of json_data is a json_string you can use it with pandas to loadit in a dataframe.

the code of JsonDF is on [GitHub](https://github.com/OsamaElsherif/JsonDF/) or you can install if from pip with :
`pip install JsonDF`
but see the readme and the codes in GitHub to understand a litle about how it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert this to a Pandas dataframe, then use koalas. It should come automatically with pyspark >= 3.2, for earlier version of pyspark can use this:

```
import koalas as ks
spark_df = ks.from_pandas(pandas_df)
```

Comment: I got it working by converting my dataset to python list and then to rdd however I will try your approach too.
Thanks